# PowerShell Get-Date writing incorrect dates on moved files

Tags: powershell

I am creating a PowerShell loop that will monitor and log 'new' files in a particular folder. I split a portion of the file's name and write that portion and the file's date into a text document when a new file is found in the folder. On the second pass, the script should read the log and if the file's name and date already exist, the write should be skipped.

My issue is that when a new file drops into the folder, the script writes the file's split name and the CURRENT date/time. At the second pass it writes the file's split name and the modified date, which is what I want. I have tried using both `Get-Date ($file).LastWriteTime` and `$file | Get-Date` (see line 25 and 26). Both cmdlets provide current date on the first pass and actual modify/create date on the second pass.

Perhaps this isn't the best way to monitor the folder. I am open to suggestions of that nature. Any advice is welcome!

```
#start loop
while($true){
    #clear $asin
    $asin = ""

    #address $outputFolder and identify $outputFiles
    $outputFiles = GCI -Path $outputFolder -Filter *.jpg -Recurse

    #isolate the $asin from each $outputFile
    foreach($file in $outputFiles){
        $asin = $file.name
        $asin = $asin.split('.')[0]
        Write-Host 'this is the asin'
        echo $asin

        #isolate the $asin + $variant from each $outputFile
        $variant = $file.name
        $variant = $variant.split('.')[1]
        $variant = $asin + '.' + $variant
        Write-Host 'this is the variant'
        echo $variant

        #get file $creation (reads 'Date modified' not 'Date created' as 'Date created' changes when files move)
        $creation = Get-Date ($file).LastWriteTime
        #$creation = $file | Get-Date
        echo $creation

        #read if $list contains $asin or not
        $listContents = Get-Content $list
        if($listContents -notcontains $asin + ' ' + $creation){
            Write-Host "Preparing to log $asin"
            $asin + ' ' + $creation | Add-Content $list
            #log asin at this point

        } elseif ($listContents -contains $asin + ' ' + $creation){
            Write-Host "$asin has already been logged"
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Consider using the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Use "CreationTime" instead of "LastWriteTime"